# Tweenmax make highlight in trun

Tags: pixi.js, gsap

I want to make highlight in turn (one highlight others hide, and next highlight, others hide....cyecling)
and these are my code

html:

```
<div id="lens_flare">
   <div id="lens_flare0" class="test"></div>
   <div id="lens_flare1" class="lens_flare test"></div>
   <div id="lens_flare2" class="lens_flare test"></div>
   <div id="lens_flare3" class="lens_flare test"></div>
  <div id="lens_flare4" class="lens_flare test"></div>
  <div id="lens_flare5" class="lens_flare test"></div>
  <div id="lens_flare6" class="lens_flare"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
 body{ 
   margin:20px;
 }

#lens_flare{
  position:relative;
  display: flex;
}

.test {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  opacity: 0
}

#lens_flare .lens_flare {
/*   position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0; */
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  opacity: 0;
}

.lens_flare {
   width:100px;
   height:100px;
   background:#CC0000;
 }

#lens_flare0 {
   background:black;
   z-index:1;
 }

#lens_flare1 {
   background:#CC0000;
   z-index:1;
 }

#lens_flare2 {
   background:#40A1F7;  
   z-index:2;
 }

#lens_flare3 {
   background:#0C8714;  
   z-index:3;
 }

#lens_flare4 {
   background:purple;  
   z-index:3;
 }

#lens_flare3 {
   background:pink;  
   z-index:3;
 }
#lens_flare6 {
   background:black;  
   z-index:3;
 }
```

JS:

```
 var tl = new TimelineMax({repeat: 100, yoyo:false});
var t2 = new TimelineMax({repeat: 100, yoyo:false});

t2.staggerTo(".test", 1.5,
    {opacity:0}
 , 1.5);

tl.staggerTo(".lens_flare", 1.5,
    {opacity:1}
 , 1.5);
```

it only success when run first time .
What else should i do to make highlight in turn always??

(stack asks me to add more details but I have told it, so add more dummy words here stack asks me to add more details but I have told it, so add more dummy words here stack asks me to add more details but I have told it, so add more dummy words here stack asks me to add more details but I have told it, so add more dummy words here stack asks me to add more details but I have told it, so add more dummy words here stack asks me to add more details but I have told it, so add more dummy words here)

Answer (score 1):

Just a simple change required, make repeat from 100 to -1, This will make it run for infinite times.

```
var tl = new TimelineMax({repeat: -1, yoyo:false});
var t2 = new TimelineMax({repeat: -1, yoyo:false});

t2.staggerTo(".test", 1.5,
    {opacity:0}
 , 1.5);

tl.staggerTo(".lens_flare", 1.5,
    {opacity:1}
 , 1.5);
```